# Swipe Refresh on Api 15

Tags: java, android

I am making an application that uses much the swipe refresh, I would like to know how to implement the swipe refresh in androids with api 15? If it is not possible how can I create the swipe for android that supports it and an alternative for others?

Comment: please be specify you have refresh `ListView` or `Whole Layout` in Page ??

Comment: I used to update textview only. The xml Layout is all within RelativeLayout.

Comment: Android has something called the Support Library that adds features like SwipeRefresh in a backwards compatible library. 

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SwipeRefreshLayout` from Support Library.

```
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html